# How to use the piecewise function to control the rotation motor in webots?

Tags: c, webots

I am creating a Webots robot controller by using C language and trying to use piecewise functions to control two rotation motors and simulate the swinging motion of a leg. One motor for the hip and another one for the knee. However, the motors only work with the "else" condition. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

This is the code:

```
#include <webots/robot.h>
#include <webots/motor.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TIME_STEP 64

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  wb_robot_init();

  WbDeviceTag Right_Hip = wb_robot_get_device("RightHip");
  WbDeviceTag RightUpperKnee = wb_robot_get_device("RightUpperKnee");

  double t = 0.0;  // elapsed simulation time
  int k = 0;

  while (wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) != -1) {
    double RightHipPosition;
    double RightUpperKneePosition;

    if ((t >= (0 + 4 * k * M_PI)) && (t <= (12/5 * M_PI + 4 * k * M_PI)))
      RightHipPosition = (35 * cos(0.417* t )+ 30)* (M_PI / 180.0);  
    else
      RightHipPosition = (35 * sin((0.625) * t )+30) * (M_PI / 180.0);

    if ((t >= (0 + 4 * k * M_PI)) && (t <= (6.241 + 4 * k * M_PI)))
      RightUpperKneePosition= -30 * (M_PI / 180.0);
    else if ((t >= (6.241 + 4 * k * M_PI)) && (t <= (2.4 * M_PI + 4* k * M_PI)))
      RightUpperKneePosition =(30 * sin (0.417 * t ) )  * (M_PI / 180.0);
    else
      RightUpperKneePosition =(-30 * sin (0.675 * t ) )  * (M_PI / 180.0);
      
    wb_motor_set_position(Right_Hip, RightHipPosition);
    wb_motor_set_position(RightUpperKnee, RightUpperKneePosition);  

    t += (double)TIME_STEP / 1000.0;
    k = k + 1;
  }
  wb_robot_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Where are the variables t and k defined? Which else branch is going to be executed? Put something like: `print("I'm here: A")` in the first `else`branch and so on for the others

Comment: Hi Dave, the full code is updated.

Comment: By the way: you should post which compiler and environment you are using, otherwise we can get different results. As a rule of thumb, you should handle float calculations as float or double. So for instance: `t >= (0.0 + 4.0 * k * M_PI)) && (t <= (12.0/5.0 * M_PI + 4.0 * k * M_PI)` . Note the `.0`after the integers. The same for the variable `k`, which is an integer. Furhtermore, why you add `0 `to `4 * k* M_PI`it is not clear to me. My suggestion: start with the only first `if`branch and print the result of the calculation. If it makes sense, then you can add the second if statement, ok?